# How to remove part of URL .htaccess - Magento

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I need to remove the last two sections [/../..] of any URL requests that include [/desc/name-of-product] via .htaccess.

Example:

[www.domain.com/product.php/id/10101/desc/apple-laptop-computer]  ->

[www.domain.com/product.php/id/10101]

[www.domain.com/product.php/id/985/desc/hp-computer] ->

[www.domain.com/product.php/id/985]

I am working on a Magento site that currently redirects old URLs (Example: [www.domain.com/product.php/id/10101](http://www.domain.com/product.php/id/10101) to the new Magento URL [www.domain.com/product-name](http://www.domain.com/product-name) via the URL Rewrite Management tool in Magento.  The problem is the old domain was allowing Google to crawl two URLs for the same product in the examples above.

Since Magento is rewriting the shorter URL in the example above properly, I need a rewrite rule to remove the last two sections [/desc/name-of-product] of any incoming links that have a [/desc/*] section.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/product.php/id/(\d+)/desc/[^/]+$ /product.php/id/$1 [R=301]
```

This will do an HTTP 301 redirect to your new URL, so Google will be informed that the page has moved permanently.

- [More informations on the Apache rewrite mod](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)